# How to remove web browser background color for remembered data

Tags: css, browser

How do I stop a browser like Chrome inserting it's pale yellow background color on fields that it remembers values of?

I have a login form which looks very ugly when Chrome has remembered the username and password for.

Answer (score 2):

Use this CSS:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: doh, didn't think to search for autofill

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work.